# How to convert old HTML to HTML5/Mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm new to web development and have created a website that isn't mobile comptabile and would like to know what the easiest way to convert my code into HTML5. Are there tutorials online on how to do this? I won't have to start from scratch will I?

Comment: Probably. If you did things right in the first place then your site would at least be somewhat mobile compatible.

Comment: HTML5 != mobile compatible. What you are looking has a name and it is "responsive web design".

Answer (score 3):

As @Niet the Dark Absol said, you probably must to start from scratch if you have not thought 
in responsiveness before (your website is full of tables everywhere and almost all the 
element widths are fixed).

I think you should go through this tutorial

http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design

Learn how to use flexible widths first and then how to do the media queries to adapt to the different device sizes.

Beware with the orientation: It could be landscape or portrait.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to learn more about "responsive web design" A responsive site "responds" to the specific browser which requests it by loading a variation that is suitable to the device's dimensions.

There are a ton of responsive web design tutorials. I like this one in particular - http://www.lingulo.com/tutorials/css/how-to-build-a-html5-website-from-scratch 
- because it is thorough and walks you through the entire proess.

Answer (score 3):

As tpb mentioned in the comments, HTML5 is not mobile-compatible by default. Start with [this article by Ethan Marcotte](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design/) on responsive web design from A List Apart.

The goal of **responsive web design** is to provide an adaptive user experience; the design of your website will respond to the parameters of the device being used to access it. If it's a mobile site, you get one view. If it's a desktop site, you get a different view. Et cetera. After you've read the above article, check out this guide on the Mozilla Developer Network:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web_Development/Responsive_Web_design

You will need to look into `@media queries` to achieve what you want. There isn't a tool out there, to my knowledge, that will convert a site into a mobile-friendly one; how would the tool know exactly what you want changed?

You can, however, run your HTML4 or XHTML code through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and set the `doctype` to "HTML5 (experimental)". This will tell you all the problems with your code, from the perspective of HTML5.

Comment: People who read this answer: yes. HTML5 is still experimental, but I would like to add that it should not be a reason to not use it. Is very near to be a standard w3c recommendation, and if we all use it and follow the standard, the future of web development will flourish  faster and stronger :)

Comment: @tpb if you're referring to the last paragraph, I only put experimental there because the doctype option on the page literally reads: **HTML5 (experimental)** :-)

Answer (score 2):

If your existing template is tableless format(ie. using DIV tags), there are possibilities to convert your template to responsive and not as HTML5. HTML5 is different. You need to code your CSS (using media queries) to support multiple devices.